# joining @ManyToOne's @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, join, criteria-api

1. Each `Account` has a `Origin` via `@ManyToOne`
2. Each `Origin`s has `Shadow`s via `@OneToMany`

With given `Root<Account>`, How can I join those `Shadow`s so that I can put some conditions for them on where?

```
final Root<Account> account;
final Path<Origin> origin = account.get(Account_.origin);
```

Comment: the JPA is jpa1.0 or jpa2.0? And can you use Root<Origin>?

Comment: In my app, I use the method join(), you can take a look at it. I don't know whether it works or not, so I decided not to post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the `@OneToMany` property in `Origin` entity is called `shadows`, you need to use [Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html) as follows:

```
Join<Origin, Shadow> shadows = origin.join(Origin_.shadows);
```

Then, you can write conditions on `Shadow`s properties like in this trivial String case, since `Join<Z,X>` has `Path<X>` as SuperInterface:

```
String name;
Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.equals(shadows.get(Shadow_.name, name));
```